# Typescript ошибка в react "В типе "{}" отсутствуют следующие свойства из типа "ReactElement<any, any>": type, props, key ts(2739)"

Tags: reactjs

Подскажите пожалуйста из-за чего выскакивает данная ошибка

> "В типе "{}" отсутствуют следующие свойства из типа "ReactElement<any, any>": type, props, key", ибо из-за нее не получается компиляция.

В `app.context.ts` если навести на AppContext.Provider высвечивается данная ошибка, а если навести на `value` то будет следующее

> Ожидалось ">".ts(1005)
> Не удается найти имя "value".ts(2304)

Но если  зайти в `Layout.tsx`, где используется AppContextProvider все хорошо и ничего не подсвечивается

app.context.ts

```
import { createContext, useState, PropsWithChildren } from "react";
import { MenuItem } from "../interfaces/menu.interface";
import { TopLevelCategory } from "../interfaces/page.interface";

export interface IAppContext {
  menu: MenuItem[];
  firstCategory: TopLevelCategory;
  setMenu?: (newMenu: MenuItem[]) => void;
}

export const AppContext = createContext<IAppContext>({
  menu: [],
  firstCategory: TopLevelCategory.Courses,
});

export const AppContextProvider = ({
  menu,
  firstCategory,
  children,
}: PropsWithChildren<IAppContext>): JSX.Element => {
  const [menuState, setMenuState] = useState<MenuItem[]>(menu);
  const setMenu = (newMenu: MenuItem[]) => {
    setMenuState(newMenu);
  };

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ menu: menuState, firstCategory, setMenu }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Layout.tsx

```
import React, { Component, FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { LayoutProps } from './Layout.props';
import styles from './Layout.module.css';
import cn from 'classnames';
import { Header } from './Header/Header';
import { Sidebar } from './Sidebar/Sidebar';
import { Footer } from './Footer/Footer';
import { AppContextProvider, IAppContext } from '../context/app.context';


const Layout = ({children}: LayoutProps):JSX.Element => {
    return(
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
            <Header className={styles.header}/>
            <Sidebar className={styles.sidebar}/>
            <div className={styles.body}>
                {children}
            </div>
            <Footer className={styles.footer}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export const withLayout = <T extends Record<string, unknown> & IAppContext> (Component: FunctionComponent<T>) => {
    return function withLayoutComponen(props: T):JSX.Element {
        return (
            <AppContextProvider menu={props.menu} firstCategory={props.firstCategory}>
            <Layout>
                <Component {...props}/>
            </Layout>
            </AppContextProvider>
        )
    }
}
```

[image: Скриншот с localhost ошибки]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переименуй файл из `.ts` в `.tsx` раз используешь в нём jsx-синтаксис.

Comment: Вот это я конечно глупый, не заметил этого. Спасибо большое!! Все заработало)

Comment: @hikiasi, раз помогло, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.